# Xcode- terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsarray

I don't know what is wrong with my code but when I run the app and click on something to see a detailed view it crashes and shows what is on the screen shot.
What should i do?
What code should i change?
Just ask if you need more screen shots.
Thanks!

Screen shot- https://plus.google.com/106403207283231647090/posts/eLDJ7V97HVr

I have tried nothing so far as i have no idea what to do.

Comment: Do think about the error message, in particular: "-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance". It is saying that the method `length` is being called on an object of NSArray type. Start looking. Read the documentation on NSArray, does it have a method `length`? Ah: no. Read more and you will find the correct method.

Comment: enable exception breakpoints, enable zombies, check your json classse

Comment: How to find the offending exception statement: Add an exception breakpoint. Go to the "Breakpoint Navigator", click on the "+" at the bottom left, select "Add Exception Breakpoint." Run the app to get the breakpoint. When you hit the exception breakpoint **click debug continue** a couple of times and you will get a backtrace and more error info.

Comment: @Matthias zombies, json? How will that help?

Comment: because that is how most of the unrecognized selector calls happen, Xcode wouldn't even compile `[myArray length]`. Though ARC helped a lot, it's still possible to handle memory wrong (legacy code with MRC, and/or unsafe_unretained). And from stackoverflow experience the offending call most likely happens because he or she thinks that an object from a JSON is a NSString, but in reality it's a string wrapped in a array. There is a good chance the exception breakpoint will point to `main()` because the offending code is in `viewDidLoad` or something that early in the app process.

Comment: Yep, there is a lot of mis-understanding about JSON, especially that the top element is usually an array.

Comment: To get NSArray number of objects, use `count`, not `length`. As in `[myArray count]`

Comment: @Zaph i tryed the exception break point and it still highlights the same line of code as shown in the image linked

Comment: Did you continue execution twice after the exception occurred. The exception prevents the rest of the error message & stack trace. Tat id Debug menu: Continue or control + command + Y.

Comment: You say it crashes when you "click on something". Click on what? A button? A table view cell? You need to post the code for whatever action is run when you "click" -- the action method, if it's a button, or didSelectRowAtIndexPath if it's a table view.

Comment: Can you post some codes from your Detailed view (i think you are doing some thing wrong in **viewdidload**)?